Is there a way to speed up Log Parser Lizard 8.7.0 queries that search through custom logs?
I use Log Parser Lizard 8.7.0 and I use the following query to search through my custom logs, but the queries are executing way too long for about an hour and 30 minutes.
SELECT top 2000 substr(FileName,49,25) AS FileName, RowNumber, RecordNumber, DateTime,     substr(to_string(FullRecord),0,23) AS Dat
,coalesce(substr(FullRecord,0,23), to_string(RecordNumber)) AS DatCoalesceRecNo, level, User,  FullRecord, Message, logger, [TimeStamp]
FROM  '\\xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz\weblogs\wwwapp\RootLOGwebapp\UltimateWebApp_log.*',
     '\\xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz\weblogs\mobapp\RootLOGwebapp\UltimateMobApp_log.log*'
WHERE to_lowercase(user) = to_lowercase('ABC278')  
order by DatCoalesceRecNo desc

I also tried not to query the logs directly from the server, but from a local folder and still no results.
Also I noticed this, the query end in 2 minutes, but the loading process of the records still continues.
